# Convert { Key : Value } Object Into Standard Variables with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I give you what I want in PHP :

```
foreach($myarray as $key=>$value) { ${$key} = $value; }
```

Now, can we do it with JS/jQuery ?

This is the jQuery input, I want the classTD value as key, in other words the equivalent of the famous PHP statement ${$key} in the example above:

```
data  = {};
$('#resul_rech_doc_fact tr.document-2 td').each(function(index) {
var classTD = $(this).attr('class');
var contentTD = $(this).text();
data = $.extend(data , { classTD : contentTD });
});
```

Comment: What's the input? Providing that would be a better illustration :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
data = $.extend(data , { classTD : contentTD });
```

Doesn't do what you expect.  It is identical to:

```
data = $.extend(data , { 'classTD' : contentTD });
```

It seems you want to evaluate `classTD` and sue it as the object's key.  You have two options:

You can assign the `data` member, modifying `data`:

```
data[classTD] = contentTD;
```

or you can use `$.extend` with a temporary object:

```
var obj = { };
obj[classTD] = contentTD;
data = $.extend(data, obj);
```

Comment: Thx, you resolved it, can you suggest me other idea to do it well.

Comment: @Amirouche Douda, I don't understand.  This solution fixed your problem; why do you need another solution?

Comment: I am looking for a way better than temporary object solution.

Comment: In that case you should say why. Otherwise it seems you're just 'picky' ;-)

Comment: I think that sje397 has found the no temporary object solution.

Comment: @strager : Yes, thank's for your effort in this thread, your response has included all the question that’s why you deserve the best answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert PHP array to object in Javascript - you can use function :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

**Example from manual:**

```
// PHP
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
$js = json_encode($arr);
echo $js;

// output
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

So you can use PHP to "echo" `$js` variable to initialize your javascript for example.

For iteration through properties of JS object you can use:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

**Example:**

```
for (key in objectInstance)
{
  alert(objectInstance[key]); // value
}
```

Comment: I have any php data !! I want the equivalent of the php statement in jquery.

Comment: @Amirouche Douda mean to say "I don't have any PHP data", as in, he isn't interacting with PHP at all.  (The grammar mistake is a common French => English error.)

Comment: @ strager : Exactly,I am sorry.

Comment: @Amirouche Douda: Ok, I see now. Stager answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
data  = {};
$('#resul_rech_doc_fact tr.document-2 td').each(function(index) {
  data[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).text();
});
```

If you want to create global variables, you can set poperties on the `window` object (but I wouldn't recommend it):

```
$('#resul_rech_doc_fact tr.document-2 td').each(function(index) {
  window[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).text();
});
```

Then, if for example you had a class called 'foo' you could access 'foo' as a "global variable". The danger here is that you could very easily overwrite important properties of the window object.

Comment: Good, but have you any idea to how to impelement $($key) with jquery.

Comment: @Amirouche Douda - that's what indexing an oject property with square brackets does. using `obj[key]` makes `key` a property of `obj`. In javascript, global variables are really just properties of the `window` object.

Comment: @Amirouche Douda, It's possible, but not recommended.  *Why* do you want to do it?

Comment: @strager : Why not recommended ?

Comment: @Amirouche Douda, Because it's a hack.  There are better ways to do what you want to do.  Why do you want to do `${$key}` specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `with`, but [`with` is considered harmful](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/):

```
var obj = { bar: 'foo' };

with (obj) {
    alert(bar); // 'foo'
}

alert(bar); // undefined
```

If you must have the loop, you can do this:

```
var obj = { bar: 'foo' };
var key, value;

with (obj) {
    for (key in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  // Never forget this check!
            continue;
        }

        value = obj[key];

        // Rest of loop here.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, What I wrote is more or less exactly what his PHP does for the inner block.  I see he edited his question with more information, though; he was trying to use a hammer to punch in a screw.

Comment: I added in a looping version in case he really wanted a loop.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, Oops; yes I am.  There is a `for` statement, however.  Simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

For all web purposes, global scope = window, so:

```
window['foobar'] = 'bar';
alert(foobar);
```

Hence the (unrecommendable):

```
var json = {'foobar':'bar'};
for i in json {
    window[i] = json[i];
}
alert(foobar);
```